# Scala Type Classes Best Practices

Tags: scala, typeclass

I'm reading through and working my way through using type classes and I came across this way of defining type classes from the Shapeless guide:

So here goes the example:

```
object CsvEncoder {
  // "Summoner" method
  def apply[A](implicit enc: CsvEncoder[A]): CsvEncoder[A] =
    enc
  // "Constructor" method
  def instance[A](func: A => List[String]): CsvEncoder[A] =
    new CsvEncoder[A] {
      def encode(value: A): List[String] =
        func(value)
      }
    // Globally visible type class instances
}
```

What I do not understand is the need for the apply method? What is it doing in this context above?

Later on, the guide describes how I could create a type class instance:

```
implicit val booleanEncoder: CsvEncoder[Boolean] =
  new CsvEncoder[Boolean] {
    def encode(b: Boolean): List[String] =
      if(b) List("yes") else List("no") 
  }
```

is actually shortened to:

```
implicit val booleanEncoder: CsvEncoder[Boolean] =
instance(b => if(b) List("yes") else List("no"))
```

So my question now is, how does this work? What I do not get is the need for the apply method?

EDIT: I came across a blog post that describes the steps in creating type classes as below:

1. Define typeclass contract trait Foo.
2. Define a companion object Foo with a helper method apply that acts like implicitly, and a way of defining Foo instances typically from a function.
3. Define FooOps class that defines unary or binary operators.
4. Define FooSyntax trait that implicitly provides FooOps from a Foo instance.

So what is the deal with point number 2, 3 and 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of those practices came from Haskell (basically an intention to mimic Haskell's type-classes is a reason for so much boilerplate), some of it is just for convenience. So,

2) As @Alexey Romanov mentioned, companion object with `apply` is just for convenience, so instead of `implicitly[CsvEncoder[IceCream]]` you could write just `CsvEncoder[IceCream]` (aka `CsvEncoder.apply[IceCream]()`), which will return you a required type-class instance.

3) `FooOps` provides convenience methods for DSLs. For instance you could have something like:

```
trait Semigroup[A] {
   ...
   def append(a: A, b: A)
}

import implicits._ //you should import actual instances for `Semigroup[Int]` etc.
implicitly[Semigroup[Int]].append(2,2)
```

But sometimes it's inconvenient to call `append(2,2)` method, so it's a good practice to provide a symbolic alias:

```
  trait Ops[A] {
    def typeClassInstance: Semigroup[A]
    def self: A
    def |+|(y: A): A = typeClassInstance.append(self, y)
  }

  trait ToSemigroupOps {
    implicit def toSemigroupOps[A](target: A)(implicit tc: Semigroup[A]): Ops[A] = new Ops[A] {
      val self = target
      val typeClassInstance = tc
    }
  }

  object SemiSyntax extends ToSemigroupOps
```

4) You can use it as follows:

```
import SemiSyntax._ 
import implicits._ //you should also import actual instances for `Semigroup[Int]` etc.

2 |+| 2
```

If you wonder why so much boilerplate, and why scala's `implicit class` syntax doesn't provide this functionality from scratch - the answer is that `implicit class` actually provides a way to create DSL's - it's just less powerful - it's (subjectively) harder to provide operation aliases, deal with more complex dispatching (when required) etc.

However, there is a macro solution that generates boilerplate automatically for you: https://github.com/mpilquist/simulacrum.

---

One another important point about your `CsvEncoder` example is that `instance` is convenience method for creating type-class instances, but `apply` is a shortcut for "summoning" (requiring) those instances. So, first one is for library extender (a way to implement interface), another one is for a user (a way to call a particular operation provided for that interface).

Answer (score 6):

Another thing to note is that in shapeless the `apply` method is not only for cuter syntax.

Take for instance this simplified version of shapeless' `Generic` and some case class `Foo`.

```
trait Generic[T] {
  type Repr
}
object Generic {
  def apply[T](implicit gen: Generic[T]): Generic[T] { type Repr = gen.Repr } = gen

  /* lots of macros to generate implicit instances omitted */
}

case class Foo(a: Int, b: String)
```

Now when I call `Generic[Foo]` I will get an instance that is typed as `Generic[Foo] { type Repr = Int :: String :: HNil }`. But if I call `implicitly[Generic[Foo]]` all the compiler knows about the result is that it's a `Generic[Foo]`. In other words: the concrete type of `Repr` is lost and I can't do anything useful with it. The reason is that `implicitly` is implemented as follows:

```
def implicitly[T](implicit e: T): T = e
```

That method declaration basically says: if you ask for a `T` I promise to give you a `T`, if I find one, and nothing more. So that means you'd have to ask `implicitly[Generic[Foo] { type Repr = Int :: String :: HNil }]` and that defeats the purpose of having automatic derivation.

Comment: Wow! I give you an up vote for that sweet explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the guide immediately after the `object CsvEncoder` definition:

> The `apply` method ... allows us to summon a type class instance given a target type:
>
> ```
> CsvEncoder[IceCream]
> // res9: CsvEncoder[IceCream] = ...
> ```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this practice of creating type classes? I have edited my question now!